# Что означает оператор ?:

Tags: c++, операторы, тернарный-оператор, задание-на-собеседовании

Что означает оператор `?:`? Увидел в следующем коде:

```
int main() {
    int x = x >= false ?: 0;
    return x;
}
```

Почему [возвращается 1](https://godbolt.org/z/oEjeeYqoY)?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D

Comment: В стандартном С++ не разрешается опускать средний операнд оператора условного выбора, так что этот код даже не скомпилируется. Я еще молчу про использование неинициализированной переменной `x` в собственном инициализаторе.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin @Алексей Шиманский вопрос про конкретно `?:` в языке С++, также есть дополнительный вопрос про поведение приведённого кода

Comment: Возвращает 1 не программа, а не сумевший скомпилировать компилятор :)

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html

Comment: @Harry есть же ссылка, по которой написано "Compiler returned: 0", "Program returned: 1"

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev можете перенести в ответ

Comment: Люди закрывают вопросы, даже не читая их похоже: не смотрят на метки, язык кода, поставленные вопросы

Comment: Это сообщение было исправлено и отправлено на проверку 23 минуты назад, но повторное открытие сообщения провалилось:

Дубликат Этот вопрос **уже был отвечен, он не уникален и не отличается от другого вопроса**.

Comment: В стандарте этого расширения нет.

Comment: @ueber, изложите, пожалуйста, в тексте вопроса, почему именно ответы на предложенные дубликаты вашего вопроса не отвечают на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Посмотрел дубликаты. Не увидел упоминания того, что gcc [разрешает](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html) пропускать операнды тернарного оператора. В дубликатах не нашёл объяснения, почему в C++ поведение кода `int x = x >= false ?: 0;` не определено.

Comment: Как минимум определённо нужно исправить заголовок, потому что его текущая формулировка вызывает сильное желание влепить дубликат (я проголосовал за переоткрытие, но заголовок и вопрос всё же стоит дописать)

Comment: У вас переменная `x` **не инициализирована**. Вероятно, в памяти (стеке), где расположена эта переменная находится **ноль или положительное число**. Оно сравнивается с `false` (нулем), результат сравнения истина (т.е. 1). Эта величина помещается в `x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это [нестандартное расширение GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals) (Clang-ом тоже поддерживается), которое иногда называют "elvis operator".

`a ?: b` означает `a ? a : b`.

Разница только в том, что `a` вычисляется один раз, а не два.

Answer (score 4):

В С++ `int x = x >= false ?: 0;` не неопредено, а не должно компилироваться.

Компиляторы совместимые со стандартом GNU С++, поддерживают бинарный "оператор Элвиса" `a ?: b`, `x = a ?: b` эквивалентно записи:

```
std::decay_t<decltype(a)> v = a;
x = v ? v : b;
```

однако в вышеприведенном случае его использование приводит к неопределенному поведению, т.к. используется неинициализированное значение x.